# Rsync via PHP exec() with SSH passwordless ssh login

Tags: php, apache, rsync

If I run the command via php exec(): It does not work. But if I use bash, it runs perfect. Any idea what the problem might be.? I was thinking maybe it is executing rsync as apache and not allowing ssh login.

```
exec('rsync -au /var/www/html/f1/ user@000.000.000.000:/var/www/html/f2/');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since none of the above suggestions would work, I had to allow the Apache user account passwordless access to the server I needed to upload images too. It works like I charm, just as needed, Thank you to all that attempted to help with my issue.

Comment: Bad solution. If someone hacks Apache, the attacker can use the passwordless access. Better use `su` which allows you to switch user.

Answer (score 7):

PHP generally runs in Apache under `mod_php`. Usually Apache is running as its own user account, independent from the real-world people who use the server.

So, the `~/.ssh` files which store the passwordless-SSH key *under your user account's home directory* are not available to PHP inside Apache, since it doesn't have your homedir. Even if Apache shared your home directory, it still wouldn't have permissions to read those files.

Comment: So the bottom line is there is no way to use rsync via php/exec.?

Comment: No. The bottom line is that you can. You just need to have the appropriate permissions set up for the user account being used.

Comment: @evan ... and the files have to be in the place it's searching.

Comment: Sure there is a way, but not on a common shared hosting account.

Comment: Your answers are unnecessarily cryptic.

@evan, are you suggesting giving apache access to the key for passwordless logins. If so< I would have to put the key it it's home directory, which, I think, is /var/www/.

Borealid, I do not understand what you are trying to say - "and the files have to be in the place it's searching".?

Comment: Hi sanmai. Both machines are dedicated servers. I have full root access. Can you suggest a way that would not compromise the security of the setup?

Answer (score 5):

My investigation of this stuff brings me to that: I **can** run rsync in php which in turn runs under apache. But I **must** to take into consideration some points:

- The home directories must exist for an user under which account a web server is launched at local computer (probably, http) and for a remote user under which account you are connecting to the remote host.
- The private authentication key (possibly with empty password) must be accessible for the http user. Corresponding public key must be added to the **remote**

  ```
  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
  ```

  file. Here `~` is the home dir of the remote user at the remote host.
- A **local** configuration file

  ```
  ~/.ssh/config
  ```

  must be created. Here `~` is the home dir of the http user at the local host. The `config` file must be accessible for the http user only. It may contain something like this:

  ```
  Host *
      User=www-data
      IdentityFile=~/.ssh/nopass_rsa
      Compression=no
      Ciphers=arcfour
      StrictHostKeyChecking=no
      UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
  ```

  Here `User` is a user name at the remote host, `IdentityFile` is a key file. Next two parameters (`Compression` and `Ciphers`) allow to increase throughput slightly. And the last two parameters allow to skip host-key checking.
- If you are dealing with `~/.ssh` directory of the local http user **and** `~` is root directory for the web-server at the same time then there is the security trouble: you (or anybody else) can access your keyfiles simply typing

  ```
  www.your-domain.com/.ssh/
  ```

  in browser. So denying access to this directory in a web-browser's config will be a good idea.

My example of php-code:

```
exec('rsync -auq remote.host.com:/archive/ ./backup_bd/');
```

which just works...

I think, I answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you specify where should SSH pick up your keys:

```
exec('rsync -e "ssh -i /home/you/.ssh/id_dsa" ...')
```

I assume that Apache runs under user that can read your `id_dsa` or `id_rsa`.

Comment: you'll run into issues trying to do this. ssh daemon is quite specific about user permissions of those files and won't use them if there's anything amiss. like trying to use them when it's not your own home folder.

Answer (score 1):

store the command in a shell script, since it has no dynamic parts, and then use exec() to execute the shell script.

```
# on command line    
echo 'rsync -au /var/www/html/f1/ user@000.000.000.000:/var/www/html/f2/' > sync_files

# On command line
chmod +x sync_files

<?php
// in php
exec('sync_files');
?>
```