# sync a remote server folder with local server folder using rsync in php?

Tags: php, shell, ssh, rsync

This code  in php it doesn't sync the "test" folders.

*php*

```
exec('/usr/bin/rsync -a /etc/test root@x.x.x.x:/etc/test');
```

But in *shell*

```
rsync -a /etc/test/ root@x.x.x.x:/etc/test/
```

is worked. So I need to sync those "test " folders by using php file.How could I do that?

Comment: I think this is the problem to me too. Just found that http://stackoverflow.com/a/9204543/1862107 .Is this the problem?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to check if you need to be a root or (sudo user) for running rsync. If yes then 
exec command will only work if it is run by same user on php-cli (not on browser by apache user).

Comment: Which user you are loggined into shell for run rsync. If it is root or any elavated permission user with sudo permission then, This rsync command may not be available to apache/www-data user which is working when php script run from browser.

Comment: as a root I'm going to log

Comment: Then first try to make a normal user and login through it, Then try rsync if you are successful then it may be interesting to see what are other problems can be, But if you getting access/permission denied then obviously you can not run this script atleast on browser.

Comment: One more thing permission may not be directly related to rsync command itself but with folder /etc/test/ which is owned by root user in normal scenario.