# Save image in remote location php

Tags: php, file-upload, remote-server

I want to save my website images in remote location with php?
I saved my image by url with this script

```
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($orginall))
```

and now I need save images in another remote server.

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to have an **`FTP`** Access to that remote location.

You could make use of the [`ftp_put()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php) for this.

**`Important Side Note`** : The `MODE` should be set to `FTP_BINARY`

Answer (score 0):

you can try rsync with exec command:

```
exec('rsync -au /var/www/uploads/x.png user@000.000.000.000:/var/www/images/x.png');
```

but you need to setup a passwordless access to remote server from your apache user. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089350/rsync-via-php-exec-with-ssh-passwordless-ssh-login) might help you accomplish that